# Rotating point on plane

Tags: 3d, rotation, plane

Given a plane (its normal), and given 2 points K1,K2 which lie on that plane. I need to rotate point K2 about K1 by given angle alpha on that plane. How to calculate the new coordinates of K2?

Answer (score 2):

Well, not knowing what language you're coding in, a general answer is something like:

```
//get some distances
distx = K2.x - K1.x
disty = K2.y - K1.y

//use Pythagorean theorem to find radius
radius = Math.sqrt(distx*distx + disty*disty)

//set new location using your angle, alpha
K2.x = K1.x + radius*cos(alpha)
K2.y = K1.y + radius*sin(alpha)
```

Comment: haha you answered my question in 2d system {x,y}, but i asked in 3d {x,y,z}

Answer (score 1):

Rotation is by definition is on an axis with a fixed pivot point.
Think of it as spinning a piece of paper under a pen change the ordination of the paper and pen only when it suits you.

Rotate the individual axis to create the one you wish to rotate by.
You'll need the distance of the point from the origin to maintain it's location through the shifting of axis.
You will also need the necessary angles to achieve your new axis.  Keep things consistent when measuring your terminal side.

Next you'll need a pivot point that is on that axis.  This is your origin prime.
Since it's rotating on a fix axis you no longer need to worry about a z-axis because it can't slide back and forth.
Use sine and cosine, distance, and your angle of rotation to find new coordinates.

Finally rotate the axis back to their original position so that you have your (x',y',z')

Axis Angle, Rotation formula, and Euler angles.
Would recommend the last one for beginners.